# probability one man with one coin and another with n-1 coins

Tags: probability

I can't find the probability of the following problem:

There are two men, the first one with one coin and the second one with n-1 coins.

Every mini-game each of them put one coin on the table, and they throw a coin to see who will take both coins. The game ends when one of them reach n coins.
What is the probability that the man with the one coin will win eventually?

Comment: Seems to be a classical gambler's ruin problem. You can google the formula.

Comment: @Peter ok, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More generally, what is your probability of winning if you start with $k$ coins, and your opponent starts with $n - k$? Call that probability $p_k$.

There are two ways you can win from this round: you can win the round, giving you $k+1$ coins, then win with probability $p_{k+1}$. Or you can lose the round, but go on to win with probability $p_{k-1}$. Since the probability of winning the round is $50\%$, we have that $$p_k = \frac 12p_{k+1} + \frac 12 p_{k-1}$$Rearranging, $$p_{k+1} = 2p_k - p_{k-1}$$
This is a 2nd order linear recursion formula. You can look up methods for solving them elsewhere, but for this one, the general solution is $$p_k = A +Bk$$ for some $A, B$. Now, you've lost when $k = 0$ and you've won when $k = n$, so $p_0 = 0$ and $p_n = 1$, which gives $A = 0, B = \frac 1n$. And so $$p_k = \frac kn$$

In particular, when $k =1$, you have $1$ chance in $n$ of winning.